# confused when using "using block" - C#

Tags: c#, .net, using, idisposable

I often use the "using" block to dispose the objects.
Today, I using HttpWebRequest to post data, and I feel confused between two method.

Method 1:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www...");
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    writer.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content));
}
```

Method 2:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www...");
using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
{
    writer.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content));
}
```

In method 2, all stream and streamwirter in "using" blocks, so certainly it will be dispose. But in method 1, I am not sure stream ***request.GetRequestStream()*** will be dispose. Can anyone explain to me? Thanks alot!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically, it depends on two things:

- Whether the `StreamWriter` constructor will ever throw an exception when passed a non-null `Stream` reference - and I don't think it will in this case. (If the stream were read-only, it would... at which point the stream wouldn't be disposed.)
- Whether `StreamWriter.Dispose` disposes of the underlying stream - and it does, unless you've called the [constructor overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712853(v=vs.110).aspx) which explicitly allows you to control that

So basically, I believe it's safe in this case... when your `using` statement disposes of the `StreamWriter`, that will dispose of the `Stream`.

As noted in comments, however, using two `using` statements means you don't need to perform this sort of reasoning.

Comment: So, method 1 is as safe as method 2?

Comment: @MinhGiang: Yes, exactly.

Comment: Are you sure about that? If Stream.CanWrite is false for whatever reason (something unpredictable happens with request) then StreamWriter constructor will throw ArgumentException and underlying stream might end up not being disposed.
Not saying its likely to happen but want to point out that some practices (like method 1)  force you to think about particular implementations (which also might change in future, of course) and some practices don't. That's the reason why i would personally always choose method 2.

Comment: @deezg: That's a good point; I think it's okay *in this case* but I'll update the post.

Answer (score 5):

A `StreamWriter` wrapping a `Stream` will close that stream when it is closed.  See the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.close%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score -2):

Both are the same. Since **using block** disposes the entire object, even anonymous objects.

Comment: No, they're not the same. The `using` statement only calls `Dispose` on the resources specified in the first part - this code is *only* okay because `StreamWriter` calls `Dispose` on the `Stream` that's passed into the constructor.

Comment: That seems to be true. I have read https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.idisposable.dispose(v=vs.110).aspx. Thank you